# How to find the indexes given the element index in a vector?

Tags: algorithms

I have a vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_{11}, x_{12}, \ldots, x_{1n}, x_{21}, x_{22}, \ldots, x_{2n}, \cdots, x_{m1}, x_{m2}, \ldots, x_{mn}]^T$ of size $m\cdot n$.

My problem is this:

> Given an index $p$ from $1$ to $m\cdot n$, find the indexes $i$ and $j$ of the corresponding element $\mathbf{x}[p]$, i.e., $x_{ij}$.
>
> Example: For $m=n=3$, $\mathbf{x} = [x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{13}, x_{21}, x_{22}, x_{23}, x_{31}, x_{32}, x_{33}]^T$ and $p=5$. Find  $\mathbf{x}[p]$?
> The answer is: $\mathbf{x}[p]=x_{22}$. Hence, $i=j=2$.

My solution is the following:

Given $p$,

$$ i = \left\lceil\dfrac{p}{m}\right\rceil,$$
$$ j = p - (i - 1) * n .$$

But I think it is wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  It looks right to me.

Comment: If $m=8$ and $n=2$ and $p=15$, my formula gives $i=2$ and $j=13$ which is not correct.

Comment: See my solution below.  You've mixed $m$ and $n$ in your formula for $j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the index $p \in [1, mn]$ and we have

$x=[x_{11},x_{12},\dots \dots, x_{1n}, x_{21},x_{22},\dots \dots, x_{2n}, \dots \dots, x_{m1},x_{m2},\dots \dots, x_{mn}]$

Or

$x=[x_{11},x_{12},\dots \dots, x_{1n}, x_{2(n+1)},x_{2(n+2)},\dots \dots, x_{2(2n)}, \dots \dots, x_{m((m-1)n+1)},x_{m((m-1)n+2)},\dots \dots, x_{m((m-1)n+n)}]$

Thus for a given $p$ we have

$$ i = \left\lceil\dfrac{p}{n}\right\rceil,$$
$$ j = \begin{cases} n & \quad \text{if } p \text{ mod } n = 0 \\ 
p \text{ mod } n & \quad \text{else}\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we know $i$ and $j$ (assume $1 \leq j \leq m$), then
$$
p = m \cdot (i - 1) + j
$$
which I will leave you to verify.  We can see then that
$$
\left\lceil 
\frac pm
\right \rceil = 
\left\lceil 
(i-1) + \frac jm
\right \rceil
$$
Since $i$ is an integer and $1 \leq j \leq m$, this indeed will always give us $i$.  Once we have $i$, we may simply evaluate
$$
j = p - m\cdot(i-1)
$$